# Nested unions in Cypher/Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've this metagraph in Neo4j:

```
:Protein ---> :is_a ---------------> :Enzyme ---> :activated_by|inhibited_by ---> :Compound
         \<-- :activated_by <---/ 

:Compound --> :consumed_by|:produced_by ---> :Transport
          \<---- :catalyzed_by -------<---/

:Transport --> part_of ---> :Pathway
```

(yes, it's biology, yes, it's imported from BioPAX).

I want to use Cypher to return all pairs of `(:Protein, :Compounds)` that are linked by some graph path. While one simple way would be to follow each possible path between the two node types and issue one query per each of them, clearly a query using some pattern union would be more compact (maybe slower, I'm assessing the performance of different approaches).

But how to write such a query? I've read that Cypher has a UNION construct, but I haven't clear how to combine and nest them, e.g., regarding the subgraphs from enzymes to transports, I would like to be able to write something equivalent to this informal expression:

```
enz:Enzyme :activated|inhibited_by comp:Compund 
join with: (
  (comp :consumed_by|produced_by :Transport)
  UNION (:Transport :catalyzed_by comp )
)
```

I've read [there should be some way](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/), but I didn't get much of it and I'm trying to understand if there is a relatively easy way (in SPARQL or SQL the above is rather simple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using Periodic Collect

In Cypher, you can break a query into steps with WITH, and you can join two lists by concatenating them together.

```
MATCH (e:Enzyme)-[:activated]->(compA:Compound), (e)-[:inhibited_by]->(compB:Compund)
WITH e, COLLECT(compA)+COLLECT(compB) as compList
UNWIND compList as comp
WITH DISTINCT e, comp // if a comp can appear in both lists
MATCH ... // Repeat above at each path step
```

## Using Union

When using Union to combine different queries, think of it like a comma separated list of queries, but instead of commas, you use the word UNION instead (Also, every query in this list has to have the same return columns.

```
MATCH (e:Enzyme)-[r1:activated]->(comp:Compound)-[r2:consumed_by]->(trans:Transport)
RETURN e as protein, comp as compound, trans as transport
UNION
MATCH (e:Enzyme)-[r1:inhibited_by]->(comp:Compound)-[r2:produced_by]->(trans:Transport)
RETURN e as protein, comp as compound, trans as transport
// Just to show only return names have to match
UNION
WITH "rawr" as a
RETURN a as protein, 51 as compound, NULL as transport
```

This is good for combining the results of completely different queries, but since the queries you are combining are usually related, most of the time COLLECT will be more efficient, and gives you better control over the results.

## Using OR

You can get the name of a relationship with the TYPE function and filter on that.

```
MATCH (e:Enzyme)-[r1]->(comp:Compound)-[r2]->(trans:Transport)
WHERE (TYPE(r1) = "activated" OR TYPE(r1) = "inhibited_by") AND (TYPE(r2) = "consumed_by" OR TYPE(r2) = "produced_by")
RETURN *
```

Note: For using OR on just they relation type, you can also use `-[:A|:B]->` for OR.

## Using Path Filtering

As of Neo4j 3.1.x, Cypher is fairly good at free path finding. (By that, I mean finding a valid path without searching all possible paths. The pattern for [relation matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength)) The upper bound is not strictly necessary, but good for preventing/controlling runaway queries.

```
MATCH p=(e:Protein)-[r1*..10]->(c:Compound)
WHERE ALL(r in RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE TYPE(r) in ["activated","inhibited_by","produced_by","consumed_by"])
RETURN e as protein, c as compound
```

## Other

- If they relationship type doesn't actually matter, you can just use `(e:Enzyme)-->(c:Compound)` or to ignore direction `(e:Enzyme)--(c:Compound)`
- If it is an option, I would recommend refactoring your schema to be more consistent (or add a relation type relevant to this matching criteria) so that you don't need to union results. (This will give you the best performance, since the Cypher planner will better know how to quickly find your results)

Comment: thanks @Tezra. I think the OR version is significantly slower, because it implies node scan operations, rather than index lookup (I've something like 1.4 million nodes).

Comment: @zakmck With the OR, it is finding all possible paths using any relation type, and then filtering the results based on TYPE. This can be significantly faster or slower depending on your data set (the less getting filtered out, the faster it will be. Usually better if you are matching nodes on IDs so that you have very limited returns). The part that slows down using collect, is that Cypher can't parallelism the query very well, so it has to do it with a less efficient sequential step search. In general, the simpler your Cypher, the better the Cypher planner is at finding your results.

Comment: @zakmck I've updated my answer to include 2 other methods of finding the results (including how to use Union)

Comment: I got the idea, but it isn't working for me. I've tried this: https://gist.github.com/marco-brandizi/6938ce6f0ab9c1370aefd224fb8670cd and EXPLAIN shows a linear plan, where, at some point, where tns is introduced, there are 0 estimated resulting rows. I'm sure there are results, cause individual paths return them. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @zakmck First, I prefer PROFILE over EXPLAIN (PROFILE actually runs it and returns data based on that run). In the linked query, you UNWIND enzs twice (was the second suppose to be comps?) Also, with COLLECT+UNWIND, the goal is to minimize the number of rows at each step, collecting and then unwinding one column doesn't help that. I recommend building your queries one step at a time. Start with `MATCH (prot:Protein) - [:is_a] -> (enz:Enzyme) RETURN *`, and add one or two steps at a time so that you can see exactly what you are getting.

Comment: Thanks @Tezra. The second UNWIND about enzs is because Enzyme is where I have a branch, going toward Transport (I missed this in my original post) and it seems Cypher doesn't interpret it as a branch/union. It's driving me mad and my understanding is Cypher de facto doesn't support UNION combined with graph subpatterns, which in turn might contain further UNION queries (as in SQL/SPARQL). Maybe it's me, but, if there is a way, sounds too complicated to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will return all paths in which an `Enzyme` is activated or inhibited by a `Compound` that is consumed, produced, or catalyzed by a `Transport`.

The query's `r2` relationship pattern is non-directional, since the directionality of `catalyzed_by` is opposite that of `consumed_by` and `produced_by`.

```
MATCH p=
  (e:Enzyme)-[r1:activated_by|:inhibited_by]->
  (comp:Compound)-[r2:consumed_by|:produced_by|:catalyzed_by]-
  (trans:Transport)
RETURN p;
```

Comment: thanks, @cybersam. Sure, your query does it in this case, but I'm evaluating the expressivity of Cypher and I'm interested in the case where directionality is relevant. Not this one, OK, but think of: (pathway1 part_of pathway2),  p1 might both be a part of another pathway and have parts itself, and users are often interested in containers only, or parts only.

Comment: OK But that is a lot of ground to cover. You can probably use Cypher to do all of that. Do you have a specific question or task that you need help with?

Comment: yes, I want to make a single query for all those paths, where there are branches, I think Tezra answer should work, I'll try it.

Comment: Sure. By the way, my answer is essentially an improvement on @Tezra's `OR` approach.

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't still found a satisfactory way to do what I initially asked, but I get quite close to it and I wish to report about.

First, my initial graph was a bit different than the one I actually have, so I'll base my next examples on the real one (sorry for the confusion):

[image]

I can work branches quite comfortably with paths in the WHERE clause (plus, in simpler cases, UNIONS):

`// Branch 2
 MATCH (prot:Protein), (enz:Enzyme), (tns:Transport) - [:part_of] -> (path:Path)
 WHERE ( (enz) - [:ac_by|:in_by] -> (:Comp) - [:pd_by|:cs_by] -> (tns) // Branch 2.1
         OR (tns) - [:ca_by] -> (enz) )                                //Branch 2.2 (pt1) 

        AND ( (prot) - [:is_a] -> (enz) OR (prot) <- [:ac_by] - (enz) ) // Branch 2.2 (pt2)
 RETURN prot, path LIMIT 30
 UNION 
 // Branch1 
MATCH (prot:Protein) - [:pd_by|:cs_by] -> (:Reaction) - [:part_of] -> (path:Path)
 RETURN prot, path LIMIT 30`

(I'm also sorry for all those abbreviations, e.g., pd_by is produced_by, ac_by is activated_by and so on).

This query yields results in about 1 minute. Too long and that's clearly due to the way the query is interpreted, as one can see from its plan:

[image]

I really can't understand why there are those huge cartesian products. I've tried the WITH/UNWIND approach, but I've been unable to get the correct results (see my comments above, thanks @Tezra and @cybersam) and, even if I was, it's a very difficult syntax.